# tkinter print values on "enter" press

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-button, tkinter-text

I need to print values on Screen When "Enter is pressed"
but not able to do so...

Currently its done with `onClick` method on button click...
How can Implement it?

I have tried
`root.bind('<Return>', getvals)` but didn't work i get error

> ```
> return self.func(*args) TypeError: getvals() takes 0 positional
> arguments but 1 was given
> ```

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def getvals():
    print("Submitting form")

    print(f"{namevalue.get(), phonevalue.get(), gendervalue.get(), emergencyvalue.get(), paymentmodevalue.get(), foodservicevalue.get()} ")







root.geometry("644x344")
#Heading
Label(root, text="Welcome to Harry Travels", font="comicsansms 13 bold", pady=15).grid(row=0, column=3)

#Text for our form
name = Label(root, text="Name")
phone = Label(root, text="Phone")
gender = Label(root, text="Gender")
emergency = Label(root, text="Emergency Contact")
paymentmode = Label(root, text="Payment Mode")

#Pack text for our form
name.grid(row=1, column=2)
phone.grid(row=2, column=2)
gender.grid(row=3, column=2)
emergency.grid(row=4, column=2)
paymentmode.grid(row=5, column=2)

# Tkinter variable for storing entries
namevalue = StringVar()
phonevalue = StringVar()
gendervalue = StringVar()
emergencyvalue = StringVar()
paymentmodevalue = StringVar()
foodservicevalue = IntVar()


#Entries for our form
nameentry = Entry(root, textvariable=namevalue)
phoneentry = Entry(root, textvariable=phonevalue)
genderentry = Entry(root, textvariable=gendervalue)
emergencyentry = Entry(root, textvariable=emergencyvalue)
paymentmodeentry = Entry(root, textvariable=paymentmodevalue)

# Packing the Entries
nameentry.grid(row=1, column=3)
phoneentry.grid(row=2, column=3)
genderentry.grid(row=3, column=3)
emergencyentry.grid(row=4, column=3)
paymentmodeentry.grid(row=5, column=3)

#Checkbox & Packing it
foodservice = Checkbutton(text="Want to prebook your meals?", variable = foodservicevalue)
foodservice.grid(row=6, column=3)

#Button & packing it and assigning it a command
Button(text="Submit to Harry Travels", command=getvals ).grid(row=7, column=3)

#enter press displays the value of the entry
# root.bind('<Return>', getvals)




root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
def getvals(event=None):
```

and un-comment

```
root.bind('<Return>', getvals)
```

That's it ...

P.S. The 'trick' is to allow one parameter in getvals, but preset it with a default value in case there is no parameter passed to the function. This way can `getvals` be used for both button click and key-press.